# Telerik issues with GridViewDataColumn font styling

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, telerik

Previously I have style defined as for `gridviewdatacolumn` as below:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Position}" 
    Style="{StaticResource blablaStyle}"/>
```

and the font color for this column will be black and font weight is normal.
Now I need to make the font weight of this column to be bold.

By following the way described at this link: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/gridview/question-how-do-i-change-the-fontweight-of-a-column.aspx

```
<telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Position}" Style="{StaticResource blablaStyle}"/>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewCell}">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </Style>
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellStyle>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
</telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
```

The font weight does updated to be Bold, but the problem now is, the font color become white color?

Please note that I need to explicitly define the font weight because `blablaStyle` is reusable across other controls but the font **does not** require to be bold.

`blablaStyle` is defined using `TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewDataColumn}"`

Answer (score 2):

Try moving your style into the Resource of the DataGridview.

```
<telerik:RadGridView.Resouces>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewCell}">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    </Style>
</telerik:RadGridView.Resouces>
```

Comment: This is not possible because only one column be bold but font weight for other columns have to be normal

Comment: Did you try set the FontWeight Property to Bold?

Answer (score 1):

I think that setting a style at the `Cell` level dismisses the style that was set at the column level. I think if you base your style at the cell level the problem will go away.

```
<telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Position}"/>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewCell}"

               <!--style it here -->
               BasedOn="{StaticResource blablaStyle}">

            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        </Style>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellStyle>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Comment: My `blablaStyle` is defined using `TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewDataColumn}"`. That's why it's now hitting error